# How to properly use and cancel subprocess in python using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a view that gets data from a form and executes a subprocess:

```
def sync_job(request, job_id, src, dest):
  form = SyncJobForm()
  check = SyncJob.objects.get(id=job_id)
  check.status = True
  check.save()
  pre_sync = SyncJobCMD.objects.get(id=1)
  p = Popen([str(pre_sync), '-avu', str(src), str(dest)], stdout=PIPE)
  syncoutput,syncerror = p.communicate()
  check.log = syncoutput
  check.status = False
  check.save()
  return render_to_response('sync_form.html', {'syncoutput': syncoutput, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I would like to have an option to cancel the running process, but I have not found how to do that with subprocess. Also, what happens when a user runs a subprocess job and navigates to another page, does the process finish in the background? Is it advisable to use Shell=True in this scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Python 2.6 you can use [`Popen.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) to kill your processes:

```
p.terminate()
```

In earlier versions of Python you can use [`os.kill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill).

```
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Also, [`Popen.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) will block until your child process has terminated. This means that the response will not get sent to the user before your sync job has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use signals (e.g. the kill signal; for more details see [documentation for the signal module](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html)):

```
import signal
p.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)
```